# gh: command not found in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-cli

I am trying to run below command in Jenkins pipeline

```
$ gh pr create --title "The bug is fixed" --body "Everything works again"
$ gh pr create --reviewer monalisa,hubot  --reviewer myorg/team-name
$ gh pr create --project "Roadmap"
$ gh pr create --base develop --head monalisa:feature
```

Getting error `gh: command not found` where general git command are working fine like `git checkout -f fedb73c252b8f058a83ab222648c08265f442876` is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Probably by installing whatever command `gh` is on the server/runners? It’s not part of fit in any way

Comment: any suggestion how to do ?

Answer (score 4):

`git` is part of every linux install and as such is available in `/usr/bin/git` via most default PATH. `gh` is [Github CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) and may not have been installed on the node running your pipeline. Or, if [installed](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md), as the jenkins agent process launches via [non-interactive shell](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/229724088-How-to-set-up-a-Jenkins-agent-to-have-the-same-path-as-the-user-when-connected-via-Remote-Desktop-), is not likely to be available in the default PATH.

You'd have to check your installation/configuration to determine the next steps. A quick fix if installed is prepend the `/full/path/to/gh`
(Not a gh user, so won't provide guidance beyond the above).

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Let me know if I can run docker node to install `gh` there.